# undefined variable in view when I pass the database data to the view from controller in laravel 6

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am new to laravel. I have two tables in my database. I want the data to be shown from the database in my select drop down. But when I pass the data to the view file it gives an error that the undefined variable $groups. Please help me. Here is my view form.

```
<form method="post" id="frm">
{{csrf_field()}}
<div class="panel-body">
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col">Group
      <select class="selectpicker boundary" data-live-search="true">
         @foreach($group as $i)
          <option value="{{$i->id}}">{{$i->gtitle}}</option>
          </select>
          </div>
                </div><br>
                <div class="row text-center">
                    <div class="col title">Title
                        <input type="text" name="title" id="title">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-footer text-center">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-info"/>
                <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset" class="btn btn-secondary"/>
            </div>   
        </form>
```

this is my controller

```
public function index(){
    $group = Group::all();
    return View::make("index")->with(array('groups'=>$groups));
}
```

this is my route

```
Route::get('/index', 'GroupController@index');
```

this is my model

```
class Group extends Model{
   protected $table = 'groups';
   protected $fillable = ['gtitle'];
  }
```

Comment: Your `foreach` references `$group` not `$groups` (notice the lacking `s`)

Comment: I have changed it but still getting error.

Comment: That's because your doing the same thing with your controller method. Your Eloquent model is filling the `$group` variable, but you're sending in `$groups` to your View.

Comment: Then show me how to do it please. I am a beginner.

Comment: some one answer please.

Comment: The error is there. It was gone for sometime now again its showing continously

Comment: please help me.

Answer (score 0):

use compact instead of an array

```
public function index(){
   $group = Group::all();
   return View::make("index",compact('group'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work, worked very well on my code.

```php
public function index(){
    $group = Group::all();

    return view('index') // location of index file
            ->with('group', $group);    
}
```

```
<select class="selectpicker boundary" data-live-search="true">
   @foreach($group as $i)
   <option value="{{$i->id}}">{{$i->gtitle}}</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: Is there anything bad with my controller or model